# Closing JQuery DropdownChecklist on selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the JQuery DropdownChecklist as available from here:

http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/

Basically I'm using some javascript to create the DropDownList as follows:

```
$("#broadbean_reg_jobSector").dropdownchecklist( 
     { emptyText: "Job Sector*" }
);
$("#broadbean_reg_jobSector").change(function() { 
      //Close Options Pop Up List  
});
```

Quick question really. Often the list is single select and in this scenario I want the pop up options list to close once a new option is selected. Instead it remains open until you click outside the boundaries of the pop up options.

Anyone who's used this list will know what I mean. I'm looking for a way to close the popup when an option is selected. I've heard `$("#broadbean_reg_jobSector").close()` should do the job but it hasn't worked for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Try this http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html. Have a look at this section: Single select with radio buttons instead of checkboxes. The example is on the right.

Comment: Why would you use a multi-select option for selects with only one option? This seems bizarre to me.

Comment: I'm not I'm using the radio buttons for a single select. These are old controls that have been used on a customer site that need to be maintained. I didn't actually choose to use this plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#s7').bind('change',function(){
    $(this).click();
    $('#ddcl-s7-ddw').css({left:'-33000px',top:'-33000px'});
});
```

If you go to that site you posted `http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html`  then type that into your console and go to the example it'll close after you select and re-open like normal.  The element is S7 so just search for that to find which one I'm talking about.

Comment: Thank you sir. Worked great. It works without the css positioning though. Just the click() seems to close the pop-up.

Comment: Ahh yeah I suppose it would at that